# my monitor gets black screen for 1 or 2 seconds while turn on the UPS

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, backup

I bought a new LED monitor and I am using it with UPS. The last few days, when my UPS works on batteries my monitor gets a black screen for just 1 or 2 seconds while the UPS starts. This did not happen earlier but after some time it has started happening.

Is there a problem with my monitor or is there an issue with my UPS? My whole system is new; if I do not connect the monitor then my monitor does not turn off for 1 second.

Comment: Does it happen when the electricity is cut, meaning at the moment that power switches from mains-power to battery-power? What model is your UPS?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes when electricity is cut then my monitor screen gets black for 1 or 2 seconds after that it's working properly. Even i purchased these all things new. And my UPS model is (Intex protector 725 )

Comment: There are a number of possibilities, e.g., 1. The UPS battery might be getting weak. 2. There might be more devices connected to the UPS, drawing a high startup current. Etc...

Comment: Do other devices connected to your UPS reboot? e.g. When the UPS switches to battery power does it disconnect power to your computer also? Or is it just the monitor?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik The UPS battery wouldn't be getting weak since the UPS is new, and there would be no startup current since the devices are already powered on.

Comment: @stickynotememo only my monitor get black screen for 1 or 2 seconds. But my CPU is working well when the switch on UPS batteries.

Comment: Your monitor's power supply just might be more sensitive than your PC. See my answer below.

Comment: @stickynotememo but if i used only monitor  on my UPS then my screen doesn't black its works fine. if I used monitor and CPU both then my monitor gets black screen.

Comment: @Monica I think the best guess here is that the UPS is either under or marginally sized for the application.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your UPS is having sags/spikes when it switches to battery power. This is not normal behavior for a UPS (the U in UPS stands for Uninterrupted). Your monitor may be the only device affected by this because it's power supply is more sensitive to fluctuations like this, but the monitor is likely not faulty.

A good idea to confirm the source of the problem is to use a non-contact pen tester/similar device near the sockets of the UPS to see if there is still current flowing when the UPS switches to battery. If the pen tester stops beeping when you turn off the power to the UPS, then you probably have some issue with the UPS. I would not recommend using a multimeter for testing unless you know what you're doing.

You should also try connecting other devices to the same UPS and see if the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

From your description I get the notion that when your UPS goes into
battery mode, it cuts or reduces the power for some short time.

The computer might still have some reserves in its accumulators, at least
enough to withstand the cut for a some milliseconds.

The power cut/reduction itself might last for just a few milliseconds,
and these 1-2 seconds are just the time needed for the monitor to reboot
itself up again.

Answer (score 0):

As you say it's a new system, I'll assume the UPS is new too.  In this case the likeliest issues are either:

a) the UPS is under or marginally sized - ie the system pulls more at once than the UPS can provide.  If it's on the margin then the UPS may recover which is why you only see a quick power out on the monitor

b) The battery or the UPS itself has a problem.

As you can see from the many comments above and downvotes on other questions, your question shows little research or effort.   You need to provide more and better info for real answers.

Info like:

- What UPS model #
- What computer
- What monitor
- What else is plugged into the ups
- How often does your ups engage and does this
  happen every time or not.

This is a community of helping to solve problems but the community expects you to put in some work.  We will point you to water but we will not bottle-feed you the drink. Questions that can be answered easily with a simple google search or two are not really appropriate here.  People expect you'd at least try that first.

Please keep these things in mind and you'll find the experience here nicer and the help you get will be more succinct and better quality.  hth and welcome to the community.